# reduce objeto javascript

Tags: javascript, json, reduce

Hola buen día me encuentro realizando un ejercicio con la función reduce de JavaScript necesito obtener un json que se agrupe por cadena , retailer y fabricante me estoy basando en el siguiente ejemplo.

```js
//filtro por Id
var array = [
  { Id: "001", qty: 1 }, 
  { Id: "002", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "001", qty: 2 }, 
  { Id: "003", qty: 4 }
];

var result = [];
array.reduce(function(res, value) {
  if (!res[value.Id]) {
    res[value.Id] = { Id: value.Id, qty: 0 };
    result.push(res[value.Id])
  }
  res[value.Id].qty += value.qty;
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

He aquí lo que estoy intentando hacer:
tengo un json con mi data inicial que cuenta con 11 objetos, utilizo reduce pero no consigo configurarlo bien.

codigo codepen : https://codepen.io/javieraguayo21/pen/PoJQmRQ?editors=0010

```js
var array = [
   {
      "cadena":"C",
      "retailer":"SI",
      "categoria":"MAYONNAISE",
      "fabricante":"ICB",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"O-S&C",
      "fabricante":"KF",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"C",
      "retailer":"SI",
      "categoria":"MUSTARD",
      "fabricante":"KF",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"MUSTARD",
      "fabricante":"ICB",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"MAYONNAISE",
      "fabricante":"KF",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"C",
      "retailer":"SI",
      "categoria":"KETCHUP",
      "fabricante":"HP",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"MUSTARD",
      "fabricante":"KF",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"C",
      "retailer":"SI",
      "categoria":"MAYONNAISE",
      "fabricante":"KF",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"KETCHUP",
      "fabricante":"HEINZ PANAMA",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"C",
      "retailer":"SI",
      "categoria":"MUSTARD",
      "fabricante":"ICB",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   },
   {
      "cadena":"W",
      "retailer":"HL",
      "categoria":"MAYONNAISE",
      "fabricante":"ICB",
      "p":0,
      "d":0,
   }
]

var result = [];
array.reduce(function (res, value) {
  //necesito que los que tengan la misma caderna , retailer y frabricante se sumen en un mismo objeto
if (!res[value.cadena] && !res[value.retailer] && !res[value.fabricante] ) {
  console.log("entro al if")
  //construyo el nuevo arreglo con la sumas correspondientes
  res[value.cadena] = { 
     cadena: value.cadena,
     retailer:value.retailer,
     fabricante:value.fabricante,
     p:0,
     d:0,
  };
  result.push(res[value.cadena]);
}
  //voy sumando los valores numericos
res[value.cadena].planters_doh_sala += value.p;
res[value.cadena].planters_doh_cd += value.d;

return res;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Necesito que me devuelva la data de esta forma, devolviéndome en este caso 6 objetos, agrupando por cadena , retailer y fabricante además sumando los valores que correspondan, solo he conseguido que me filtre por cadena :(

```
[
{
   "cadena":"C",
   "retailer":"SL",
   "fabricante":"ICB",
   "p":10,
   "d":15,

},
{
   "cadena":"W",
   "retailer":"HL",
   "fabricante":"KF",
   "p":25,
   "d":5,

},
{
   "cadena":"C",
   "retailer":"SI",
   "fabricante":"KF",
   "p":12,
   "d":10,

},
{
   "cadena":"W",
   "retailer":"HL",
   "fabricante":"ICB",
   "p":10,
   "d":10,

},
{
   "cadena":"C",
   "retailer":"SI",
   "fabricante":"HP",
   "p":15,
   "d":30,

}, 
{
   "cadena":"W",
   "retailer":"HL",
   "fabricante":"HP",
   "p":12,
   "d":10,

}
```

]

Muchas gracias quedo atento a sus comentarios.

Comment: Entiendo entonces me recomiendas hacer todo con filter() voy a probar gracias.

Comment: ¿No habia quedado resuelta esta pregunta?  ¿Porque la has modificado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como en preguntas similares, en mi opinión se puede usar `.reduce()` y en el parámetro acumulador guardar el criterio y el resultado acumulado en la forma `[[criterio],[acumulado]]`. `criterio` y `acumulado` siempre van a tener la misma longitud, es por ello que el índice que obtenemos en un array nos sirve en el otro.

La diferencia estaría dada en este caso en que el criterio lo conforman 3 propiedades. De manera similar a como trataría el problema una base de datos relacional (con una tabla sin clave primaria) sería crear un campo único conformado con la combinación de los 3 campos que sirven de criterio, un hash único.

En este caso el hash es la simple concatenación de los campos, pero podría ser de otra manera.

```js
var array = [{"cadena":"C","retailer":"SI","categoria":"MAYONNAISE","fabricante":"ICB","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"O-S&C","fabricante":"KF","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"C","retailer":"SI","categoria":"MUSTARD","fabricante":"KF","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"MUSTARD","fabricante":"ICB","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"MAYONNAISE","fabricante":"KF","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"C","retailer":"SI","categoria":"KETCHUP","fabricante":"HP","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"MUSTARD","fabricante":"KF","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"C","retailer":"SI","categoria":"MAYONNAISE","fabricante":"KF","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"KETCHUP","fabricante":"HEINZ PANAMA","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"C","retailer":"SI","categoria":"MUSTARD","fabricante":"ICB","p":0,"d":0},{"cadena":"W","retailer":"HL","categoria":"MAYONNAISE","fabricante":"ICB","p":0,"d":0}];


const res = array.reduce((p, c) => {

  const hash = c.cadena + c.retailer + c.fabricante;

  const idx = p[0].indexOf(hash);

  if (idx < 0) {

    p[0].push(hash);

    delete c.categoria

    p[1].push(c);

  } else {

    for (let pr in p[1][idx]) {

      if (pr !== "cadena" && pr !== "retailer" && pr !== "fabricante") {

        p[1][idx][pr] += c[pr];

      }

    }

  }

  return p;

}, [[],[]])[1];

console.log(res);
```

En cada iteración, nos fijamos si `c.cadena + c.retailer + c.fabricante` ya esta en el primer sub array del acumulador (`p[0]`), si no está lo insertamos, y además insertamos el objeto completo en el segundo sub array (`p[1]`), si ya existe, sumamos las cantidades en (`p[1]`).

Comment: @JavierAntonioAguayoAguilar No acepté la edición que hiciste porque no daba lo mismo, ahora lo cambié por los datos mas enmascarados que incluíste.